# Ph.D. distinction levels

Tags: phd, thesis

I just passed my Ph.D. defence in a French speaking University. Ph.Ds, here, can be passed with different "distinctions" levels (from "acceptable" to "excellent"). What is the proper term in English for this kind of distinctions? (what we would call "mention excellente" in French...)

Comment: probably the closest is [cum laude etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_honors), but you should be careful about translating terms.

Comment: Here in the US, Ph.D.s have no distinctions.  Distinctions are used only with lesser degrees.

Comment: @GEdgar There are often university awards given to the most outstanding theses. This happens at my large university in the US and I believe I've seen these in graduation booklets for other schools (Berkeley I think). If someone won one of these awards it wouldn't be surprising if it was included in their CV, so I'm not sure if I see the distinction (I'm sorry).

Comment: If it's for a CV, I wouldn't bother translating.  It's impossible to get translate the nuances of the levels, and it's very likely anyone who cares either knows enough French to know what they mean or knows a colleague who does.

Comment: @GEdgar the Wikipedia article on cum laude suggests that they might be used with PhDs

Comment: @PVAL: In most European systems, all theses are given what amounts to a grade, although typically it is not called a grade, rather something like "distinction". This is what the OP means by "distinction". In the US some exceptional theses are singled out for what amount to prizes, but a thesis defense as such only results in a positive or negative decision. As a matter of course there is no distincion made between theses that are accepted.

Comment: @PVAL: For what it's worth, Theodore Kaczynski's (unabomber) dissertation won such an award.

Comment: Georgetown University in the U.S. confers doctoral degrees "with distinction" if they are deemed outstanding and deserved. There are no levels of distinction, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to echo what's being said in the comments, in the United States, there are no distinctions with degrees... you simply have either earned it or you haven't.

Also, for what it's worth, "PhD ABD" is not a real degree, even if you list it on your resume. Just sayin'.

Comment: What's Ph.D. ABD?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD ABD = All But Dissertation

Comment: "Almost Became Doctor."